# Adding custom objects to a Parse backend iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit, parse-platform, mkmapitem

I am building an application that stores locations in a list and later maps them.

The problem I'm running into is an inability to save MKMapItems to a Parse database. I need to save these MKMapItems because they are the only unique identifiers for locations on a map that would not require searching the map again (ex.location name, ex. address).

So my question is, how can I save an MKMapItem to a Parse database?

And to follow up, if it is not possible to save an MKMapItem, how else can I save these items to a map so that I do not have to re-search?

MKMapItem: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html

Parse:
https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS

EDIT

Another detail that might help: I'm using this to store information about particular venues. For example restaurants. I don't necessarily want to be creating a new map annotations at that mark if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Parse has prebuilt support for it, but you can definitely create your own class to do it:

1) You can create an `MKMapItem` from an `MKPlacemark`, using this init method

```
- (id)initWithPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
```

2) `MKPlacemark` is basically just a coordindate and address, created using this init method

```
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate addressDictionary:(NSDictionary *)addressDictionary
```

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` can easily be stored in a custom class on Parse. If you care, you can also store the relevant address values too.

3) When you need to fetch `MKMapItem`s, you actually fetch the underlying `MKPlacemark` coordinates, create `MKPlacemark`s, and finally create `MKMapItem`s using each.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay getting back to you. I'm not quite sure how I should store the CLLocationCoordinate2D in parse. You say to use a custom class, but can you provide details on how this is done?